# msvc2010: ошибка: C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Использую `std::multiset`
Он определен в подключаемых заголовках vs2010
Компилятор (msvc2010) ругается на то, что я неверно инициализирую экземпляр std::multiset::const_iterator, а также неверно использую оператор сравнения.
Возможно, конечно это из-за неполной поддержки компилятором стандарта C++11.
Но все же я решил спросить.
Можно ли это как-то обойти?
Ошибка возникает и для неконстантных итераторов.

```
typedef std::multiset<
    const RuleInfo*, // пользовательская стрктура
    RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore // оператор сравнения
> RuleInfoConstPtrMSet;
...
void CriteriaDialog::addButtonClicked() {
    RuleInfoConstPtrMSet::const_iterator it = allowable_rules_.begin(); // 1-я ошибка

    if ( ui->combo_box_param_->currentIndex() )
        std::advance( it, ui->combo_box_param_->currentIndex() );

    if ( it == allowable_rules_.cend() ) return; // 2 ошибка
    // ...
}
```

Первая ошибка:

```
C:\Files\qt\universal_tsw_client\src\tsw-client\ui\criteria_dialog.cpp:328: ошибка: C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>" в "std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>"
with
[
    _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<const RuleInfo *,RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore,std::allocator<const RuleInfo *>,false>>
]
and
[
    _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<const RuleInfo *,RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore,std::allocator<const RuleInfo *>,true>>
]
Ни один конструктор не смог принять исходный тип, либо разрешение перегрузки конструктора неоднозначно
```

Вторая ошибка:

```
C:\Files\qt\universal_tsw_client\src\tsw-client\ui\criteria_dialog.cpp:333: ошибка: C2678: бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
with
[
    _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<const RuleInfo *,RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore,std::allocator<const RuleInfo *>,true>>
]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\exception(470): может быть "bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,const std::_Exception_ptr &)" [найдено при поиске с зависимостью от аргументов]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\exception(475): или       "bool std::operator ==(std::_Null_type,const std::_Exception_ptr &)" [найдено при поиске с зависимостью от аргументов]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\exception(481): или       "bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,std::_Null_type)" [найдено при поиске с зависимостью от аргументов]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\system_error(408): или       "bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &)" [найдено при поиске с зависимостью от аргументов]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\system_error(416): или       "bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &)" [найдено при поиске с зависимостью от аргументов]
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(2015): или       "bool operator ==(QBool,bool)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(2016): или       "bool operator ==(bool,QBool)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(2017): или       "bool operator ==(QBool,QBool)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qchar.h(392): или       "bool operator ==(QChar,QChar)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h(527): или       "bool operator ==(const QByteArray &,const QByteArray &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h(529): или       "bool operator ==(const QByteArray &,const char *)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h(531): или       "bool operator ==(const char *,const QByteArray &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(908): или       "bool operator ==(QString::Null,QString::Null)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(909): или       "bool operator ==(QString::Null,const QString &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(910): или       "bool operator ==(const QString &,QString::Null)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(936): или       "bool operator ==(const char *,const QString &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(949): или       "bool operator ==(const char *,const QLatin1String &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(962): или       "bool operator ==(const QLatin1String &,const QLatin1String &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(1202): или       "bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const QStringRef &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(1205): или       "bool operator ==(const QString &,const QStringRef &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(1208): или       "bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const QString &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(1212): или       "bool operator ==(const QLatin1String &,const QStringRef &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(1215): или       "bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const QLatin1String &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(1236): или       "bool operator ==(const char *,const QStringRef &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h(1238): или       "bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const char *)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qsize.h(83): или       "bool operator ==(const QSize &,const QSize &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qsize.h(233): или       "bool operator ==(const QSizeF &,const QSizeF &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qpoint.h(80): или       "bool operator ==(const QPoint &,const QPoint &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qpoint.h(238): или       "bool operator ==(const QPointF &,const QPointF &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qrect.h(162): или       "bool operator ==(const QRect &,const QRect &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qrect.h(599): или       "bool operator ==(const QRectF &,const QRectF &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qmargins.h(77): или       "bool operator ==(const QMargins &,const QMargins &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(198): или       "bool operator ==(const QHashDummyValue &,const QHashDummyValue &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h(413): или       "bool operator ==(const QVariant &,const QVariantComparisonHelper &)"
c:\qt\4.8.5\include\qtnetwork\../../src/network/kernel/qhostaddress.h(137): или       "bool operator ==(QHostAddress::SpecialAddress,const QHostAddress &)"
c:\files\qt\universal_tsw_client\src\tsw-client\ui\../criteria_typedefs.h(83): или       "bool operator ==(const RuleInfo &,const RuleInfo &)"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtree(315): или       "bool std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>::operator ==(const std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree> &) const"
with
[
    _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<const RuleInfo *,RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore,std::allocator<const RuleInfo *>,true>>
]
при попытке сопоставить список аргументов "(std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>, std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>)"
with
[
    _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<const RuleInfo *,RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore,std::allocator<const RuleInfo *>,true>>
]
and
[
    _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<const RuleInfo *,RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore,std::allocator<const RuleInfo *>,false>>
]
```

UPD: Пользователь @AnT заметил, что в листингах не было объявления объекта `allowable_rules_`, он объявлен как объект типа `typedef std::<const RuleInfo*, RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore>` видимо,  msvc не кастит итераторы multiset к set,или такого преобразовния не было в реализации STL от Microsoft, т.к. в gcc такой код собирался.

Comment: Вы что-то недоговариваете. Как объявлено ваше `allowable_rules_`? Судя по первому сообщению об ошибке (последний параметр `_Tset_traits` в одном случае `true`, а в другом `false`) у вас наблюдается какая-то мешанина из `std::set` и `std::multiset`. Еще раз: как объявлено ваше `allowable_rules_`?  Почему в вопросе нет этой очевидно необходимой информации?

Comment: точно, извиняюсь, я долго не пользовался msvc и разрабатывал в основном под Linux.`std::set<
    const RuleInfo*,
    RuleInfoCmpRulePtrParMore
> allowable_rules_;`   мой недосмотр.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Какое в данном случае значение имеет "я долго не пользовался msvc и разрабатывал в основном под Linux"?

Comment: Привык к ошибкам gcc, поэтому упустил такую очевидную ошибку. И тем не мене версия программы почему-то там собиралась. Видимо я скопировал не ту версию.

Comment: Я замечаю, что VS2017 тоже по какой-то причине допускает смешивание итераторов обычного set и multiset. Не знаю, есть ли в этом какой-то глубинный смысл или это просто совпадение, но аналогичные причины могут работать и в GCC.

Comment: Однако в любом случае, если ваше `allowable_rules_` объявлено не с типом `RuleInfoConstPtrMSet`, то почему здесь вы пытаетесь использовать `allowable_rules_` именно с этим типом? На что вы надеялись?

Comment: @AnT этот код компилировался под Linux, видимо просто опечатка. Этот код мой, мои постфиксы к multiset - MSet, к set - Set. Вот видимо неправильно указал, gcc с использовал с поддержкой C++11, где как-раз таки есть реализация multiset, и, видимо каст от multiset::iterator к set::iterator, чего в msvc нету, дело даже скорее всего не в компиляторах, а в реализациях STL.